# iOS 4.2 simulator files?

Tags: ipad, ios4, ios-4.2

Where are the files associated with my app in the iOS 4.2 simulator - need to look at my sqllite DB and I can't find it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/APP_UUID/`

In Xcode 6, check
`~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DEVICE_UUID/data/Containers/Data/Application/APP_UUID/`

Comment: Thank you sir, couldn't remember how to get there

Comment: There is no "iPhone Simulator" under my Application Support.is not exist.

Comment: @Albert You are probably looking under your main file system. Look for  the library folder in your user directory