# Copying files to/from iOS application's data directory?

Tags: ios

Post-install, how do I copy a config file (to set some logging parameters in my particular case) to my iOS application's data directory?

Or, relatedly, how do I copy a data file *from* my app's data directory for me to examine for debugging purposes?

Ideally, I'd like to use the USB connection that I already have set up for debugging. And without having to write my own file transfer manager that ships in my application.

I'm more or less looking for the iOS equivalent of Android's `adb push` and `adb pull`.

Comment: by "copy" do you mean networked OTA copy?

Comment: @nycynik, clarified in my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you need to do what you are saying you want in your question- but I could be wrong.

When an app runs in the simulator, it runs in a directory on your computer, so running the simulator, to get a file from it, or add a file for it, you just copy the file from that folder.

here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287005/ios-4-2-simulator-files) to the location of the file.

Comment: The simulator is easy.  What about when the app is on a device as is mentioned in the original question (USB means device not simulator)